# Dynamically allocate memory in c with unknown type

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, malloc

So I'm supposed to implement a set that can contain any type of object in C. How do I dynamically allocate memory based on type of that object. Or i.e., how do I find out size of object whose type is unknown given only a void pointer pointing to it?

```
void set_add(set *s, const void *item) {
  ...
  s->items[s->size] = malloc(sizeof(*item) * ??);
  ...
}
```

Comment: You can't find out the size of the object pointed to in a portable way without the size being passed in.

Comment: Perhaps your assignment doesn't say anything about maintaining a set filled with *copies* of your items. So long as whatever that `const void *` is pointing to has lifetime as-long/longer than your set and identity is address-based, you know the size; it is the size of a `const void*`.  If the assignment truly calls for copying you need to know the size. There is no escaping that.

Comment: Is your `set *s` passed as a parameter guaranteed to contain the correct `s->size` prior to the function call?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, unless you pass the size to your `set_add` function.

What you **do** know is the size of the pointer to the object, though. So instead of storing a copy of the pointed to object, you're probably supposed to take ownership of the object (thus, you become responsible of `free`ing it when no longer needed) and store the pointers to the objects in your set.

```
struct set {
  void **items;
  size_t free_space;
  size_t capacity;
};

void set_add(set * s, void * obj) {
  // dedupe logic
  assert(! (s->free_space > s->capacity));
  if (s->free_space == s->capacity) {
    void ** new_items = realloc(s->items, s->capacity * 2);
    // error handling please!
    s->items = new_items;
    s->capacity *= 2;
  }
  s->items[s->free_space++] = obj;
}
```

Note that I sacrificed the `const` because I made `items` non-const, too. Otherwise `free` will complain when passing it a `const` qualified pointer (target). The other possibility would be a cast to remove the `const` just before the `free`. Depends on what you want to achieve.

Comment: I'm not sure the *"you can't"* note is correct. Looking at the question `set *s` is passed as a parameter, and the `s->size` member appears to contain the needed size. It is worth a question to the OP to confirm. As it sits, you are correct that `size` is required, it is just ambiguous whether or not that is already provided.

Comment: Indeed, though I'd assume the the size member holds the current size of the set, rather than the (then for all elements constant) size of an element. @DavidC.Rankin